# Encrypting string in C++

Tags: c++, encryption

I have a client server based application where user is presented with login screen in the client. It then passes the credentials to the server which does the authentication. Client-server communication happens via a web service hosted on the server using https protocol (with TLS1.2 support). Client passes username and password to the web service. I am thinking of encrypting the password evethough I am using https based communication. My questions are:

1. Is it worthwhile to do a second level of encryption for password?
2. Is there any good practices to follow (like which algorithm to use etc)?
3. Its a MFC based application written in C++. Does windows provide any methods to do this?

Comment: I think you should ask the first 2 questions at [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/help). About question 3, I can't recommend any resources, but the golden rule about cryptography is: do not roll out your own solutions, as they are *certainly* vulnerable to some weird kind of attacks that you would never think of unless you are a real expert. Instead, take some libraries made by others that are considered reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I agree you should ask the first two question [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/help).

Yes windows provides some methods to do encryption.  There is a whole library called [Microsoft CNG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376210(v=vs.85).aspx)

Do not be tempted to use their obsolete "Cryptography API" - CAPI.

**DO NOT** be tempted to write crypto code yourself.

Comment: I know "link only" answers are bad - but I think explaining the whole of CNG is a bit long for SO, and even if MS move their help page, a search for "Microsoft CNG" will find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTTPS/TLS1.2 and pin the certificate there is no reason to further encrypt the data.

https encrypt the entire transmission except for the URL address, thus the query string, etc is encrypted.

Encrypting the password just moves the problem to how will the encryption key be shared between the client and server?